# Here Maps: Matrix routing status returns 401 with ApiKey

Tags: here-api

I successfully created a request to the matrix routing api.

When I want to check the status, I get error 401 (No credentials found). I pass the ApiKey as a url parameter like I did when sending the request:
[https://matrix.router.hereapi.com/v8/matrix/{requestId}/status?apiKey={ApiKey}](https://matrix.router.hereapi.com/v8/matrix/%7BrequestId%7D/status?apiKey=%7BApiKey%7D)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution, disable auto redirects:

```
var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler() { AllowAutoRedirect = false };
var client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
```

Comment: Tnx. I had the same problem and this was the solution.